# Automating Pyenv Setup/Python Installation on Windows

Tags: windows, devops, pyenv

I'm currently working on adding Python 3 to a few of the Windows servers I use. Pyenv looks like a good option for managing different versions of python. Unfortunately I haven't figured out how to automate the setup. I'm using pyenv-win on windows, https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win, and when I run pyenv install it launches a gui for the python installer. Is there a way to install python through pyenv using just the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You are running into a "helpful" feature of Win 10. To turn it off:

- hit the windows key
- type "app alias"
- use the interface to turn off the options for python.exe and python3.exe

I am in a hurry so can't provide substantiating links right now - check the github page for pyenv-win for more info.